# OpenJPA: how is concurrency controlled when result of a stored procedure is mapped to an object?

Tags: stored-procedures, concurrency, openjpa

I have just started researching on OpenJPA, trying to understand if it addresses my needs. 
I've done some reading on OpenJPA concurrency control and I know how to create a named stored procedure (@NamedStoredProcedureQuery) and map its resultset to a list of POJO instances. But, I don't understand the combination and couldn't find any specific documentation...

If I don't do the SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT operations through JPA, but just use it to map the result of storedprocedure to my POJO, will it still be able to handle concurrency?

Problem is that, I will use a storedprocedure to SELECT objects, and later when I change them, I use a different stored procedure to UPDATE those objects.
How would it know if another storedprocedure updated same table before I do it?
Does it keep track of the state of my POJO object (assume it is marked by @Entity)?
Does it query the table before calling any stored procedure that is mapped to it (let's assume I tell JPA that this object can be mapped to which table)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used OpenJPA but there are few ways to analyse this.

First way is to look for Hibernate's showsql like configuration in OpenJPA.

Next thing you could try is to look for any query logs. MySQL provides query logs.

JPA providers like Hibernate typically generate one-to-one queries. I.e. for an update it does not SELECT into the table first. JPA also defines locking mechanisms which the JPA providers implement.

https://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_2_0_concurrency_and

This combined with isolation levels can help you tune the behavior.

Further, you can use check and update. Something to the effect of following query.

```
UPDATE some_table SET column_a = 456 where column_a = 123 and id = 1
```

Lastly, an advice against using stored procedures. JPA's utility is at vendor independence which is reduced by use of stored procedures.